# How do I render full color emojis using Python PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Im trying to using [OpenSansEmoji](https://github.com/MorbZ/OpenSansEmoji) and PIL to render text with emojis to a PNG.

```
font = ImageFont.truetype("OpenSansEmoji.ttf",size=20,encoding='unic')
img = Image.new("RGBA", (400,100), (54, 57, 63))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((0,0), responceText, (255,255,255), font=font)
img = img.convert('RGB')
img.save("images/image_text.png")
```

But I get a textbox with a square instead, on some common emojis like the thumbs up, it renders it but line style. Is there any way I can get full color emojis?

Comment: From the link for OpenSansEmoji, *"All symbols are in monochrome."*. Maybe you could check out the **[pilmoji](https://pypi.org/project/pilmoji/)** package?

Comment: @SashSinha pilmoji is garbare which needs connection to remote server to work, what essentially is a certified clown activity